# Changing the Text of Parent <li> without destroying the child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code as follows

```
function liReplace(str) {
    document.getElementById('srch').innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li id='srch'>
        <a href="#">All Categories</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Gadgets</a>
                <ul>
                    <li onclick='liReplace("DVD")'><a href="#" >DVD</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">XBOX</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ps2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cellphone</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Locations</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Indoor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I wanted to change the All Categories to what ever is clicked

see  `<li onclick='liReplace("DVD")'><a href="#" >DVD</a></li>`

I used javascript function to change innerhtml but the whole child li's are gone after.

Help on how to get the part of first Li text only.

Comment: please show the `liReplace` function.  Your HTML on its own does not help.

Comment: added lireplace function. using innerhtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it - you can just replace the text within the `<a>` element at the top `<li>`:

```
function liReplace(str) {
    $('#srch > a').text(str);
}
```

Where the `>` ensures that only the immediate child gets changed.

Comment: thanks it worked. Just for learning purposed. What if I want to change the middle or last LI. thanks again!

Comment: You mean middle in the hierarchy?  You could use `li > ul > li:nth-child(x) > a`, where `x` is that element's relative position within its parent.

Comment: I dont know if I should post for this follow up question..  on <li onclick='liReplace("DVD")'><a href="#" >DVD</a></li> how do I change "DVD" to like this.text().. this also involves the <a href="#">Gadgets</a> part..because I could also click them and need to change the parent LI.

Comment: Ask in a new question.  You will need to include much more detail about which clicks on which elements will change which _other_ elements.  Describe the behaviour desired.

Answer (score 1):

Use ">" to enforce the child

```
function liReplace(txt) {
    $("#srch > a").html(txt);
}
```

Comment: Sorry i thought I could choose two answers. I chose Alnitak because of the explanation.